MYSQL - Results from 2 joined tables with the same column names
Say I have two tables that I get the required data from using:
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.* FROM `Table1` INNER JOIN Table2 on Table1.ID = Table2.LinkID;

But Table1 and Table2 both have a column Title. When running the query in PHP the resulting rows array gives me the Title from only one table, since they share the same column name.
I know I can do this:
SELECT Table1.*, Table1.Title AS T1_Title, Table2.*, Table2.Title AS T2_Title FROM `Table1` INNER JOIN Table2 on Table1.ID = Table2.LinkID;

Which is fine. But the two tables have many columns, with many of them with the same name.
Is there a way of getting all the results from both tables, with the table name being prepended by default without having to alias every field?

no.. you need to be explicit for each column, and not use *

@Randy Thanks for confirming. That is what I have been doing but was hoping there was a neat way around it.

Sorry, there's no shortcut. The simplest solution is to not use duplicate names in different tables. Even id columns should have a prefix that identifies the table.

@Barmar Thanks. If only. I am working on someone else's database.
